# FingerPrint Best SDK

Tags: fingerprint

I'm about to create a web service that will be used in finger print enrollment, identification, and verification, I have only one constraint that I have to store the finger prints images, and personal data on an oracle database,
What's best SDK to buy?
Is it the best practice to store the images in the database with the personal data?

BR,
Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

I did some development with [Verifinger](http://neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html), it supports a decent [list of fingerprint scanner vendors](http://neurotechnology.com/cgi-bin/fingerprint-scanners.cgi) and offers a lot of samples in a number of programming languages. There are some other SDKs vendors such as [Griaule](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/new/content/gbs-forensic-edition/#sdk), they might be worth looking at.
I don´t see any issues to have your personal and biometric data stored in the same database as long as it is well secured.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with various SDK ranging from **DigitalPersona** (now Crossmatch), **Neurotechnology SDk** (they have various SDK and not hardware manufacturer), **Grauile**; I can say using Digitalpersona SDk is what I prefer most if you do not have issues using any of their own supported readers. Your cost mainly will be hardware and SDK initial cost. If you intend to use hardware from various vendors, then Neurotechnology verifinger is a good option but be ready for device or dongle-based licensing.

Pertaining to data storage, you can store the template in a main database while you store the raw bitmap in a separate non-transaction database (size is usually large). The raw bitmap is required in case of future migration where you need to convert template to another format